# PHP compare dates (trial expired)

Tags: php, date, compare

I'm trying to compare the start + end (+7 days) with current date. If the startdate is +7 days before current date it should get an 'active' message. If the current date is today or more then 7 days it should get an 'expired' message.

**$mysettings->getTrial(); gives 2015-09-07**

This is what I have

[EDIT]

```
                <?php $today = time();
                  $start = $mysettings->getTrial();
                  $end = strtotime("+7 days", $start);
                  echo $end;

                    if ($end >= $today) {
                        echo 'Trial active';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Trial expired, get PRO';
                    }


                ?>
```

[EDIT]

Problem now is $end = strtotime ("+7 days", $start); - A non well formed numeric value encountered in

(PS: I'm sorry, just a PHP beginner)

Comment: `if ($end >= $today)` .. `=>` and `>=` are different.

Comment: Your syntax is all over the place. You should bracket your `if(){}` and a greater than or equal to operator looks like `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'tests' need to be enclosed in brackets..

```
$today = time();
$start = strtotime($mysettings->getTrial());
$end = strtotime("+7 days", $start);

echo date('jS F M Y',$end);

if ($end > $today) {
    echo '<br>Trial active';
} else {
    echo '<br>Trial expired, get PRO';
}
```

Comment: Ooops..  it can be '==' or '>' or '>='... (but not '=>')

Comment: Now i'm getting a : A non well formed numeric value encountered in  message.. Problem is line: $end = strtotime("+7 days", $start);

Comment: Try: $end = strtotime("+7 days", strtotime($start));

Comment: Notice has gone (yay!) But somehow I'm getting this result: 1437004800Trial active

Comment: So your date is a timestamp.  Just format it with date().  (see edited example above)

Comment: Thank you Chris! This helped a lot and now I'm getting what I did wrong. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `$today = strtotime ("Today");` with `$today = time();`.

Assuming `$start` is good, since it comes from elsewhere, replace `if $end => $today {` with `if ($end > $today) {` and it should be fine.